# JSF commandButton URL parameters

Tags: jsf

I would like to make a button which navigates to a different URL and pass some request parameters through in the URL. The outputLink works but I would like a button, the commandButton looks good but I can pass parameters.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `h:commandButton` doesn't fire a `GET` request, but a `POST` request, so you can't use it. If you're already on JSF 2.0 and the target page is in the same context, then you can use the `h:button` for this:

```
<h:button value="press here" outcome="otherViewId">
    <f:param name="param1" value="value1" />
    <f:param name="param2" value="value2" />
</h:button>
```

(no `h:form` is required here as in `h:outputLink`). This will create a button which goes to `otherViewId.jsf?param1=value1&param2=value2`.

But if you're not on JSF 2.0 yet, then your best is just to grab CSS to style the link like a button.

```
<h:outputLink styleClass="button">
```

with something like

```
a.button {
    display: inline-block;
    background: lightgray;
    border: 2px outset lightgray;
    cursor: default;
}
a.button:active {
    border-style: inset;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With the button you associate an `action`, which is a method in the backing bean
You can set params in the backing bean and read them when you press the button, from the method linked to `action`. The action method should return a `String`, which will be read by the Navigation Handler to check if it has to move to a new page, according to the configuration in the `faces-config.xml`.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Press here" action="#{myBean.action}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean.propertyName1}" value="propertyValue1" />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean.propertyName2}" value="propertyValue2" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Backing bean:

```
package mypackage;


public class MyBean {

    // Init --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private String propertyName1;
    private String propertyName2;

    // Actions -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void action() {
        System.out.println("propertyName1: " + propertyName1);
        System.out.println("propertyName2: " + propertyName2);
    }

    // Setters -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void setPropertyName1(String propertyName1) {
        this.propertyName1 = propertyName1;
    }

    public void setPropertyName2(String propertyName2) {
        this.propertyName2 = propertyName2;
    }

}
```

This example is taken from  [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html)  (BalusC blog, probably he will come and tell you to check that link but I'm faster! :P)

Of course to achive this the bean has to be set as `session scoped`. If you want it to be `request scoped` you can follow the steps [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#PassingGETParametersFromJSFToBackingBeans)