# f:param doesn't work with h:commandButton

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat7, myfaces

i'm using eclipse 3.6.2 (Helios) , Tomcat 7 , MyFaces 1.2.9

i have no problem when i use f:param into the h:commandLink but when i put f:param into h:commandButton it doesn't work . what's the problem ?

this sample work fine :

```
<h:commandLink value="Click here" action="#{myBean.action}">
<f:param name="parameterName1" value="parameterValue1" />
<f:param name="parameterName2" value="parameterValue2" />
</h:commandLink>
```

but it doesn't

```
<h:commandButton value="Click here" action="#{myBean.action}">
<f:param name="parameterName1" value="parameterValue1" />
<f:param name="parameterName2" value="parameterValue2" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In JSF 1.x, the `<f:param>` is only supported in `<h:commandLink>`, `<h:outputLink>` and `<h:outputFormat>`, not in `<h:commandButton>`. That support is only in JSF 2.0 and newer.

You have at least 4 options:

1. Use `<h:commandLink>` instead. If necessary use CSS to style it to look like a button. See for an example also [JSF commandButton URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004620/jsf-commandbutton-url-parameters/3005428#3005428).
2. Use `<f:attribute>` or `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` instead. See also [Communication in JSF](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html).
3. Pass them as method arguments `action="#{myBean.action('param1', 'param2')}"`. Tomcat 7 is a servlet 3.0 container which supports EL 2.2 which in turn supports passing method arguments. You only need to make sure that your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 3.0. See also [Invoking methods with parameters by EL in JSF 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325298/invoking-methods-with-parameters-by-el-in-jsf-1-2).
4. Upgrade to JSF 2.0. It offers so much advantages over JSF 1.x. See also [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0) and [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html).

Comment: You meant h:commandLink in the first option, also link is pointing to opposite styling. I attempted do edit it but has been rejected.