# javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010016: Not a multi part request at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.loadParts

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2.2

I've a JSF 2.2 page with the below file upload form deployed to WildFly 8.2.0.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputFile value="#{filePair.miscPart}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="validationResult" />
</h:form>
```

When I submit it, I get the below exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010016: Not a multi part request
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.loadParts(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParts(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:459)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.FileRenderer.decode(FileRenderer.java:91)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:831)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.decode(UIInput.java:771)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1226)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processDecodes(UIInput.java:676)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1221)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1221)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:929)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot to set the form encoding type via `enctype` attribute.

```
<h:form>
```

It defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is insuitable for sending binary data such as binary files sent via `<input type="file">`. You need to set it to `multipart/form-data` as per the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) when using `<input type="file">` element (as generated by JSF `<h:inputFile>`). Here's a cite of relevance from the HTML specification:

> **`enctype`** = 
>   This attribute specifies the [content type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#form-content-type) used to submit the form to the server (when the value of [`method`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-method) is "post"). The default value for this attribute is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". The value "multipart/form-data" should be used in combination with the [`INPUT`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-INPUT) element, `type="file"`.

Thus, fix it accordingly:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

#### See also:

- [What is multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156068/params-not-getting-passed-to-backing-bean-for-hcommandlink-under-richpopuppane/12159693#12159693)
- [How to upload file using JSF 2.2 <h:inputFile>? Where is the saved File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677397/how-to-upload-file-using-jsf-2-2-hinputfile-where-is-the-saved-file)

Comment: Would've been nice if it would set that `enctype` to `multipart/form-data` automatically if it noticed a file component inside the form. Perhaps an improvement for future JSF versions?